# aide --init show lots of errors

Tags: linux, dependencies, intrusion-detection, aide

I have a brand new centos 6.2  server. The first thing I did is yum -y install aide and then next I did aide --init. Below is a whole lot of errors I got.What does it means must I reinstall it? Or leave it ?

```
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lusermod: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/NetworkManager: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/rtacct: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/tcpdump: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/dnsmasq: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/getsebool: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/ownership: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/modem-manager: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/pluginviewer: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/sasl2-shared-mechlist: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/ifdhandler: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/mklost+found: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/vpddecode: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/skdump: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/getpcaps: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lpasswd: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/tmpwatch: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/ck-log-system-stop: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/alternatives: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/dump-acct: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/luseradd: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/nstat: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/efibootmgr: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/sasldblistusers2: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/e2freefrag: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/sa: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lgroupadd: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/ss: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/dmidecode: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/sktest: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/fdformat: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/saslpasswd2: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/selinuxenabled: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/pppstats: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/capsh: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/togglesebool: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/kppp: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lgroupmod: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/cracklib-unpacker: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/getcap: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/avcstat: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lnstat: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/filefrag: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lid: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/bonobo-activation-sysconf: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lockdev: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/mcelog: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/cifs.upcall: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/pcscd: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/brctl: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/logrotate: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/wpa_passphrase: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/pppdump: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/lsof: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/ck-log-system-start: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/setcap: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/rtkitctl: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/latencytop: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/wpa_cli: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/sbin/saned: at least one of file's dependencies has changed since prelinking
Error on exit of prelink child process
```

Comment: did you `yum update` the server before installing aide?

Comment: yes I did that. So then I run this now /usr/sbin/prelink --all and it does not appear any more? Am I on the right track please help me confirm. What is this prelink error actually?

Comment: When I ran the /usr/sbin/prelink this is what I got /usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/lib64/xulrunner-2/libxul.so: DT_JMPREL tag not adjacent to DT_RELA relocations
/usr/sbin/prelink: /usr/lib64/xulrunner-2/libmozsqlite3.so: DT_JMPREL tag not adjacent to DT_RELA relocations

Comment: looks like some of the libraries got updated without recomputing prelink. The JMPREL/RELA conflict is in a number of bug reports. readelf -d is suggested to check the elf structure, and if really important, relink from source rpm, otherwise ignore.

Comment: I did this readelf -d so what option must I choose now. So what is the best solution you suggest? IS it some critical which might corrupt my system in near future?

Comment: From what I read (and I do not use prelink at all), the only issue is that firefox start up time will be slightly higher. I.e. not an issue.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov this machine wont be using any gui is purely a server. So I do anything about it? Or just go ahead with installing my other stuff? Is it a bug itself?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3572/discussion-between-dmitri-chubarov-and-newbie14)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact problem after installing a binary that did not use the normal packaging system dependency resolution to properly share libraries.  Here are the steps I used to resolve the problem.

1. First look at the library dependencies for one of the binaries that
   caused the `aide` error message.  In my case `trashapplet`:

   ```
   for LIB in $(ldd /usr/libexec/trashapplet | awk '{print $3}' | grep '^/' | sort -u); do echo $(dirname $LIB); done | sort -u
   ```
2. Next, make sure each directory used by the binary is configured for processing with prelink in `/etc/prelink.conf`.  Add any missing directory to the `/etc/prelink.conf`.  In my case, this was:

   ```
   -l /usr/local/oracle/product/*/lib
   ```
3. Repeat as necessary.

In my case the binary hijacked the distro's `/lib64/libexpat.so.1` library.  Because the new library was located outside the normally-prelinked set but overlapped with the existing library, it caused the mis-match at load time no matter how frequently I `prelink`ed.

Comment: Why is this error cause in the first place is it indicating something serious?

Comment: @newbie14: For some values of "serious":

 "Did a hacker break in": No.
 "Could it cause bugs and/or security vulnerabilities?": Probably.  Binaries are being loaded against a version of the library they were probably not compiled against.

Comment: No this is a fresh machine which I did installation and had this issues so what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and found the answer through Red Hat (you need an account). Here is what it says:

> The message "at least one of file's dependencies has changed since
>   prelinking" means that one of the libraries that the application
>   depends on (perhaps glibc) has been upgraded since last prelink cron
>   job run (which by default runs every 14
>   days(PRELINK_FULL_TIME_INTERVAL=14 ). Prelink is only able to verify
>   files if their dependencies haven't changed. As soon as it is
>   reprelinked, the errors will go away.
>
> Prelinking only really helps when running applications in a
>   workstation type setup  where launching and closing the same
>   application over and over is a common operation. Prelinking doesn't
>   really do anything so server loads where a process is loaded into
>   memory and runs for the duration of the server's uptime.
>
> Prelinking can be disabled by editing /etc/sysconfig/prelink and
>   setting
>
> PRELINKING=no
>
> To undo all the prelink information, run the following command  as
>   root:
>
> prelink -ua

Since the problem was on my server, not a workstation, the fix worked perfectly (disabling prelinking in /etc/sysconfig/prelink and running "prelink -ua"). If you want to continue to prelink, make sure that you have a prelink cron job ... it's usually in /etc/cron.daily/ and should've been installed by default with your system. Also make sure that crond service is running and /etc/crontab (or /etc/anacrontab) is configured to execute /etc/cron.daily/. The cron job keeps your prelinking up-to-date or else you get those error messages.